# HTML5 buffer and play audio with createMediaElementSource()

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I am using the audio API to get instant playback of a sound in iOS 6 in a web page. I have done it using an Ajax call, like the documentation suggested and that works great. However, I read you can do the same without the Ajax call using  createMediaElementSource() https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html

However, it seems that loading from an audio node in this way, you can't use the noteon(0) method - so can't actually play the sound!

Has anyone got this to work? I want to create a few reusable functions that degrade to using the audio element, rather than relying on the Ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

You can still call play() and pause() methods on the audio element you passed to createMediaElementSource().
The following site demonstrates the use of MediaElementAudioSourceNode:
http://webaudioapi.com/samples/audio-tag

Comment: Thanks, I need to investigate that a little further, as it still seems to have a delay on iOS, which the ajax call does not.